# I want to make a single dictionary from a dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge, nested

I have dictionary which contains dictionary as value for it's keys. I want to create a single dictionary out of it and also if there are keys repeating it should add the values of those keys

So I have

```
temp_dict = {0: {'a':1, 'b':2}, 1: {'c':3,'d':4}, 2: {'d':5,'e':6}}
```

I tried this for making it a single dictionary (not adding the values from same keys in this step though)

```
empty_dict = {}
for d in empty_dict:
    for k,v in d.items():
        empty_dict[k] = v
```

But the above code is also showing error. And then the next step is too add the values from same key.

I expect the output as

```
new_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':9, 'e':6}
```

d has 9 by adding values from the both the 'd's above.

Comment: Have you at least tried a simple for-loop approach?

Comment: where is your code that you have tried and what part didn't work. People will be happy to help you. However this is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from the stdlib

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

for i in temp_dict.values():
    c.update(i)

Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 9, 'e': 6})
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. But is there a way to do without counter()